# How to use big spreadsheets in Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Or may be some other options.
We want to use Google Docs for all office operations, but faced with problem of big Excel files >3 000 records.
Is it justified to use DB and web interface over DB?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it's justifiable.

A Google Spreadsheet may have up to [400 thousand cells](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=37603). So depending on how many columns your records have, it may fit nicely or not in an Google Spreadsheet.

If you have more than 133 columns (4e5/3e3) it will not fit, actually if you have around 100 columns (for this amount of records 3e3), I advise not using Google Spreadsheet as it will be too near the limit.

Google Fusion tables may be suitable to you, as it does not have such limitation, it's actually a [250MB total size limitation](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171181&topic=27017&ctx=topic) per account.

Comment: it is now 2 million cells, but still way too small :)

Comment: and i found out it counts empty cells as well